# Jsoup- Iterate element to get the unique text content

Tags: jsoup, extract, element

I hope you can help me :-)

I want to extract the text content from a html page.
I used jsoup library, but having problem with html page like

```
<div>
<p>paragraph
</p></div>
<div>
division content
</div>
```

When extract Paragraph content i got 'paragraph' as output and when extract div content gets 'paragraph division content'

What i require a unique text as result- once i fetch

content as 'paragraph' then fetching  content will not include

content

how can do it ?

Here is my code

```
Elements page_content=doc.select("p");
Elements div_content=doc.select("div");
String Content=page_content.text()+" "+div_content.text();
```

Comment: What is your code? What is the expected result of **each** query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Elements page_content=doc.select("p");
Elements div_content=doc.select("div:nth-child(2)");
String Content=page_content.text()+" "+div_content.text();
```

Comment: If it helped and does what you;ve asked for, please accapt the answer.

Comment: @TDG good point. At least you got my +1 , even if OP lost interest

Comment: ownText() - function will do the unique tag based content extraction